# using laravel 5.5 and get error to create my controller?

Tags: laravel

I am using laravel 5.5 and I get an error when I create my controller.

```html
$ php artisan make:controller MyDatatablesController
```

I want to create new controller but I get this error:

> [Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError]
>     Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '=>' (T_DOUBLE_ARROW)

Comment: Check your codes. I think you have an error in routes or Modules.

Comment: Go back through the files you've changed and check for syntax errors. You may find more useful information in the `laravel.log`

Comment: as @fubar said, check logs in  `storage/logs/laravel.log`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your command is perfect their is some error in your project check your recent changes in your project

Answer (score 0):

You're having an error on your own code. Probably it's a code not always executed. Try executing the command in verbose mode to have more information about the error

```
php artisan make:controller MyDatatablesController -vvv
```